# ggplot theme_set() only works intermittently

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'll often set a theme early on in a script, with a specific base font size.

```
# CODE BLOCK 1
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 20))
```

Then I'll want to switch the theme and the font size for a different plot later on in my script. I will try to accomplish this with code like below.

```
# CODE BLOCK 2
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  theme_set(theme_gray(base_size = 6))
```

I just ran these two code blocks on a fresh R session and when I ran *code block 2* the theme and base font size did not change to the arguments listed above. I immediately ran *code block 2* again and the theme and font size changed to the arguments shown above. Why is `theme_set()` only working intermittently?

My session info follows:

```
OS: Windows 7 64 bit
R: 3.4.4
R Studio: 1.1.442
ggplot2: 2.2.1.9000
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the correct way to use theme set?

Comment: We set the theme and **then** call ggplot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this. See also here `?theme_set`

```
theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 20))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]

```
theme_set(theme_gray(base_size = 6))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

Or simply without the `theme_set`function

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_bar() +
  theme_gray(base_size = 6)
```